# JS - Getting input from a form & putting it into array and then appending a new row to table (DOM)

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, appendchild

I'm trying to get input from a form and putting it into an array and then putting that array into a new row to a table using DOM manipulation. I have this so far and while it is receiving the value I put in, the value is not displayed in the table but a blank row is inserted. Please help!

```
(function(){

var theValue;

var formControls = document.getElementById('theForm');
var table = document.querySelector('info');

var handler = function (){
     var tbody = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody').item(0);


     for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var tr = 'tr' + [i],
        tr = document.createElement('tr');
        var displayValue = 'td' + [i],
        displayValue = document.createElement('td');
        var enteredValue = this['present-value'].value;
        theValue = document.createTextNode(enteredValue);
        tr.appendChild(displayValue);
        tbody.appendChild(tr);

        return false;
    }




} // end handler

formControls.onsubmit = handler;


})();
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
<div id="controls">
    <h2>Controls</h2>
    <form id="theForm">
        <fieldset>
            <label for="present-value">Enter Value</label>
            <input id="present-value" name="present-value" type="text">
            <button type="submit">Add</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="display">
    <h2>Values</h2>
    <table class="info">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Value</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo?

Answer (score 0):

Just some comments:

```
> var table = document.querySelector('info');
```

That attempts to get an element with a tag name of "info". There is no such element in HTML.

```
> var tr = 'tr' + [i],
> tr = document.createElement('tr');
```

That will overwrite the previous value of *tr*

```
> var displayValue = 'td' + [i],
> displayValue = document.createElement('td');
```

and that will overwrite the previous value of *td*.

```
> var enteredValue = this['present-value'].value;
```

I presume that *this* is a reference to the form. Does it have a "present-value* attribute or property? This line tries to get the *present-value* property of the form, then read it's *value* property. Likely it just throws an error or returns *undefined*.

Can you post some minimal HTML to go with the code? As far as I can see, the above will not do anything useful.

Comment: I've posted the html with it. The query selector is supposed to select a table class called table. I forgot to include the '.' in front of it, but the error still persists.

Answer (score 0):

You might look at JQuery's .serializeArray() method:

http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/